# Asterisk PHP AGI & phpagi-asmanager not showing full output

Tags: asterisk, agi

I am executing a php agi command using phpagi-asmanager.php class on my Asterisk 14 box and it is only showing a 1 line output instead of showing the full results.

```
require_once( '/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/phpagi-asmanager.php' );

$agi = new AGI_AsteriskManager();
$agi->connect();

$result = $agi->Command('queue show');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

The above code only outputs:

```
Array
(
 [Response] => Success
 [Message] => Command output follows
 [Output] => 
)
```

Instead of showing the list of Queues and its members

Answer (score 0):

Use tcpdump and see communication between your app and asterisk server.

Also check, that same command works on asterisk.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I doubled check it, the asterisk command is working from the command line.

Comment: Now you have check what asterisk sended to your app by network.

Comment: This is DEBUG task. Offtopic here.